# Processing both Unix & DOS files

Tags: delphi

My app proccess text files which are somtimes produced on WIndwos systems & sometimes Linux.

What is the minimal effort way to handle both line endings?

That is to say, for each line, I want to get a string with the line ending stripped.

Comment: You need to provide more info. What does "handle" mean? What are you doing with the files? How are you doing it now?

Comment: +1 sorry, @Ken, I have update the question. I am not currently handling it as I just encountered my first Unix file

Comment: Your update doesn't help much. If you want to read the entire file into memory the a string list is all you need. But if you want to process the file line by line then you need something else. I guess that's what Ken was driving at. And as for you "not currently handling it", well, you are currently handling Windows files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TStringList` handles both Windows and Linux line endings just fine.

```
program TestLFs;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Classes;

var
  SL: TStringList;
  s: string;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile('YourUnixFile.txt');
    for s in SL do
      WriteLn(s);
    SL.LoadFromFile('YourWindowsFile.txt');
    for s in SL do
      WriteLn(s);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```